# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument for open()

Tags: python, replace, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = input("URL:")
grab_page = requests.get(url)
parse_page = BeautifulSoup(grab_page.text, "html.parser")
file_name = parse_page.title.string.replace("\\,()", "")


newfile = open(file_name + ".html", "w+")
newfile.write(grab_page.text)
```

When I try to run the above code, with [this particular URL,](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html) where the title of webpage is "How to Install JDK 8 (on Windows,
Mac OS, Ubuntu) and Get Started with Java Programming" I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LKT/PycharmProjects/webpagegrabber/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    newfile = open(file_name + ".html", "w+")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'How to Install JDK 8 (on Windows,\r\nMac OS, Ubuntu) 
    and Get Started with Java Programming.html'
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You are passing `'How to Install JDK 8 (on Windows,\r\nMac OS, Ubuntu) and Get Started with Java Programming.html'` to `open`, which isn't a valid path according to your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file name contains invalid characters (`\n`, `\r`). So you cannot create such a file in Windows. As described in the [Windows Developer Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1
> through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
> are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
> Streams.

Comment: I tried replacing those characters with .replace() function. Any idea why is it not working?

Comment: It does not appear in your code, but I would check if there are other sneaky invalid characters (maybe print the filename as a hex string as well)

Comment: specifically this line of code:

    file_name = parse_page.title.string.replace("\\,()", "")

then i try to pass it as an argument for open()

Comment: you don't replace '\n' and '\r' there. If you want to replace them you should call replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')

Comment: also - replace does not take a regular expression as a parameter, so it will only replace occurrences of the entire string

Comment: Yes, that solves my issue. Thanks for the tip, learned something today!